# jQuery slideToggle direction ! Abnormal behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello I have manually made a toggle navigation button that kicks in at 980px on my project. It works fine, it displays the navigation.

However, when I try to slideToggle the menu to make it show in a more elegant way, the direction of the height growht is from bottom to top.

I have attached a video with the behaviour. Here it is: https://www.screencast.com/t/wAkkHiRP5h

A jsFiddle with the functionality can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/grimhilt/7x49x6sk/

The HTML is:

```
<nav id="main-navigation" class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a href="#navbar-brand-centered" class="main-nav-trigger">
                <span>
                    <em aria-hidden="true"></em>
                </span>
            </a>
            <div id="logo" class="navbar-brand navbar-brand-centered">
                <a href="/">
                    <img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="logo" class="img-responsive">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div id="navbar-brand-centered">
            <ul class="nav navbar navbar-nav navbar-left">
                <li><a href="#">ALbums</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Boxes</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">DVD Cases</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Journal</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

The CSS:

```
#main-navigation.nav-open #navbar-brand-centered,
#navbar-brand-centered  {
    /*
        show primary nav - mobile only
        :target is used to show navigation on no-js devices
    */
    display: block;
}
#main-navigation #navbar-brand-centered {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #9e865f;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
    box-shadow: 0 14px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    border: none;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

The jQuery is:

```
var mainHeader = $('#main-navigation');

mainHeader.on('click', '.main-nav-trigger', function(event){
    // open primary navigation on mobile
    event.preventDefault();
    mainHeader.toggleClass('nav-open');
    $( "#navbar-brand-centered" ).slideToggle( "slow" );
});
```

How can I make the #navbar-brand-centered height animate from top to bottom as it should? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Can you provide a working jsfiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I can't at the moment. Working on it now

Comment: @Brad https://jsfiddle.net/grimhilt/7x49x6sk/ - here is a working example. The styles are not all there, but the functionality is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove these lines:

```
mainHeader.toggleClass('nav-open');
$('#navbar-brand-centered').toggleClass('is-visible');
```

and add `display:none` to the `main-navigation` id

```js
var mainHeader = $('#main-navigation');
mainHeader.on('click', '.main-nav-trigger', function(event) {
  // open primary navigation on mobile
  event.preventDefault();
  //        mainHeader.toggleClass('nav-open');
  //      $('#navbar-brand-centered').toggleClass('is-visible');
  $("#navbar-brand-centered").slideToggle("slow")
});
```

```css
#main-header {
  position: absolute;
  min-height: 100px;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}

#main-navigation {
  display: none;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 45px 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: #151725;
  border: none !important;
}

#main-navigation.nav-open #navbar-brand-centered,
#navbar-brand-centered ul:target {
  /*
            show primary nav - mobile only
            :target is used to show navigation on no-js devices
        */
  display: block;
}

#main-navigation #navbar-brand-centered {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #9e865f;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  box-shadow: 0 14px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  /*-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;*/
  /*backface-visibility: hidden;*/
}

#main-navigation.nav-open #navbar-brand-centered {
  display: block;
}

#main-navigation .main-nav-trigger {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  right: 0;
}

#main-navigation .main-nav-trigger em,
#main-navigation .main-nav-trigger em::after,
#main-navigation .main-nav-trigger em::before {
  /* this is the menu icon */
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 2px;
  width: 22px;
  background-color: #9e865f;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header id="main-header">
  <nav id="main-navigation" class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a href="#navbar-brand-centered" class="main-nav-trigger">
          <span>
            <em aria-hidden="true"></em>
           </span>
        </a>
        <div id="logo" class="navbar-brand navbar-brand-centered">
          <a href="/">
            <img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="logo" class="img-responsive">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div id="navbar-brand-centered">
        <ul class="nav navbar navbar-nav navbar-left">
          <li><a href="#">ALbums</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Boxes</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">DVD Cases</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Journal</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for enlightening me. I was approaching the button animation wrong. I used the jQuery you gave me and toggled a class on the button itself for the button animation. It now works flawlessly. Thank you so much !

Comment: Glad I helped!!

Answer (score 1):

Ok so i think the key here is understanding what the `.slideToggle()` does.

It will toggle between `display:block;` when shown and `display:none;` when hidden. It does this with a sliding animate on the height of the element.

In your code you are also messing with the display properties:

`$('#navbar-brand-centered').toggleClass('is-visible');`

`mainHeader.toggleClass('nav-open');`

So your adding `display:block;` then the jQuery fucntion is turning toggling it.

So if you remove this, it works. see eaxmple:

```js
    var mainHeader = $('#main-navigation');
    mainHeader.on('click', '.main-nav-trigger', function(event){
        // open primary navigation on mobile
        event.preventDefault();
        //mainHeader.toggleClass('nav-open');
        //$('#navbar-brand-centered').toggleClass('is-visible');
        $( "#navbar-brand-centered" ).slideToggle( "slow" )
    });
```

```css
    #main-header {
    position: absolute;
    min-height: 100px;
    z-index: 10;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}
#main-navigation {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 45px 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background-color: #151725;
    border: none !important;
}
    #main-navigation.nav-open #navbar-brand-centered,
    #navbar-brand-centered ul:target {
        /*
            show primary nav - mobile only
            :target is used to show navigation on no-js devices
        */
        display: block;
    }
    #main-navigation #navbar-brand-centered {
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #9e865f;
        z-index: 2;
        top: 100px;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        display: none;
        box-shadow: 0 14px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        overflow: hidden;
        text-align: center;
        border: none;
        /*-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;*/
        /*backface-visibility: hidden;*/
    }
    #main-navigation.nav-open #navbar-brand-centered {
        //display: block;
    }
        #main-navigation .main-nav-trigger {
        float: right;
        display: inline-block;
        height: 100%;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        right: 0;
    }
        #main-navigation .main-nav-trigger em,
    #main-navigation .main-nav-trigger em::after,
    #main-navigation .main-nav-trigger em::before {
        /* this is the menu icon */
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        height: 2px;
        width: 22px;
        background-color: #9e865f;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header id="main-header">
    <nav id="main-navigation" class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a href="#navbar-brand-centered" class="main-nav-trigger">
           <span>
            <em aria-hidden="true"></em>
           </span>
                </a>
                <div id="logo" class="navbar-brand navbar-brand-centered">
                    <a href="/">
                        <img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="logo" class="img-responsive">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div id="navbar-brand-centered">
                <ul class="nav navbar navbar-nav navbar-left">
                    <li><a href="#">ALbums</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Boxes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">DVD Cases</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Journal</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Thank you. I solved the problem. The issue was exactly what you told me about. I have finished my page and everything woks flawlessly.